# Call back for column resize

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is there any callback available for ag-grid column resize.

I could not find any doc related to column resize call back.

Sample code:

```
var columnResized = function(params){
console.log(params);
};

gridOptions.columnResized = columnResized;
var myAgGrid = new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv,gridOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Grid Name : ag-grid**

**Column Resize Event:**
we can fetch column resize event by **columnResized**, as shown below.

```
<ag-grid-angular
        class="ag-theme-alpine ag-grid-container-full"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        (columnResized)="onColumnResize($event)"  //  <-----
      >
```

In .ts file
as resize event will triggered multiple times, so we use setTimeout to act as debouncing efect to handle that.

```
   public setTimeInstance = null;

  onColumnResize(event) {

    if (this.setTimeInstance) clearTimeout(this.setTimeInstance);

    this.setTimeInstance = setTimeout(() => {

      let newColumnState = this.columnApi.getColumnState();

      this.someActivity();  // Do some activity  like storing

      clearTimeout(this.setTimeInstance);


    }, 1000); // after one seconds

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onColumnResized` instead of `columnResized`

Example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

There is a build in param that tells you when all events are finished.
Thanks to @JobayerAhmmed for this answer.

```js
onColumnResized(params) {
  if (params.source === 'uiColumnDragged' && params.finished) {
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
}
```

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (columnResized)="onColumnResized($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```